# Why Request Parameter or @ModelAtrribute wont work for Generic class?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, generics, httprequest, wrapper

`@ModelAttribute` uses `@RequestParam` for each variable inside the `Pojo class` and `@RequestParam` uses `request.getParameter()`(Am I Correct??).

But from [Spring MVC Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) it's sure that `@ModelAttribute` populates the request parameters to bind to argument fields.

- But my question is if `pojo` class is a `generic` class then it's not possible to get the parameters,***Why***?

  - Is it because the type is considered as `Object` always instead of passed argument type(Pojo).
  - Is request object/mapping of variables is not capable of handling `Generics`?
- If its a `Wrapper` class than it will work fine because it will be sure about the param type(i.e Pojo class).

Sample Code to check:

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generic", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String generic(@ModelAttribute Generic<ParamClass> generic) {
    return null;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/wrapper", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String wrapper(@ModelAttribute WrapperClass wrpr) {  //wrpr contains value
    return null;
}
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class WrapperClass {
    private ParamClass paramList;
    //getter & setter
}
```

**Generic class**

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private T paramList;
    //getter & setter
}
```

**Pojo Class**

```
public class ParamClass {
    private String param;
    // getter & setter
}
```

**Jsp form**

```
<form action="/wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="paramList.param" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So one more question is,is it always required to have `Wrapper` class for each type? Is there any better solution(except having all param type variables in one class)?

Comment: Your sample won't work in either case. Also your assumptions/understanding is wrong `@ModelAttribute` and `@RequestParam` have nothing to do with each other. Spring binds on property paths and uses the parameter names for that, but that is all that there is in common.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tested the code and pasted here...For wrapper it will work for sure...[Documentation-SO]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370581/spring-mvc-please-explain-difference-between-requestparam-and-modelattribute

Comment: Your code won't work. The JSP will not post to the correct URL nor does the name of the input type match the path of the binding... So it simply cannot work. If it works, it appears to work but binding will at least not work.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated the question with proper parameter and url

Comment: The main issue is that it is a generic typed nested path. To do binding it needs to create an instance of the nested path. But due to the nature of generics that isn't possible.

Comment: @M.Deinum Why that so? we are mentioning Generic type there...which will become  `private ParamClass paramList;`

Comment: As stated that is the nature of generics... Those aren't available after compile time anymore... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens

Comment: @M.Deinum one thing is clear now...Generics has nothing to do with except some compatible for all required class/type...Java always use casting for generics while compiling..But,is `@Model Attribute` doesn't give support to casting(indirectly supporting generics)?? and also in compiling if it comes to know the type(atleast to cast) why can't it's used   request mapping

Comment: Because the type isn't there anymore... Spring has no way to dtermine the type of `T` anymore at runtime and as such cannot instantiate an instance of that type using reflection... And thus cannot do binding.

Comment: Ok Convert this to answer(with documentation reference) and any best solution to avoid creating multiple wrapper classes(all param type variables in one class)